# Boost giving strange result for ode integration

Tags: c++, boost, ode

I ran the following code which solves a simple differential equation. The result seems to depend on tsteps. The result I get for tsteps = 100 is 9.688438503116524e-15, but for tsteps = 1000 the answer is 7.124585369895499e-218 much closer to the expected result.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp> // odeint function definitions
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;
typedef std::vector< double> state_type;
int tsize = 1;
void my_observer( const state_type &x, const double t );
void initarrays(state_type &x)
{
    x[0]=1.0e0;
}
void my_system( const state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , const double t )
{
    dxdt[0]=-x[0];
}
void my_observer( const state_type &x, const double t )
{
    std::cout<<t<<" ";
    for(int i=0;i<tsize;i++)
    {
    std::cout<<x[i]<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    std::cout.setf ( std::ios::scientific, std::ios::floatfield );
    std::cout.precision(15);
    int size=tsize;
    state_type x0(size);
    double err_abs = 1.0e-12;
    double err_rel = 1.0e-12;
    double a_x = 1.0;
    double a_dxdt = 1.0;
    initarrays(x0);
    double t0 = 0.0e0;
    int tsteps = 1000;
    double t1 = 500.0e0;
    double dt = (t1-t0)/((double)tsteps);
    typedef runge_kutta_fehlberg78< state_type > solver;
    typedef controlled_runge_kutta< solver > controller;
    my_observer(x0,t0);
    for(int ts=0;ts<tsteps;ts++)
    {
        integrate_adaptive( make_controlled( err_abs , err_rel , solver() ), my_system, x0 , t0+ts*dt , t0+(1+ts)*dt , dt);
        my_observer(x0,t0+(1+ts)*dt);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get your problem. It is normal that for numerical integration higher numbers of steps increase the precision of the result until the numerical instability becomes the limiting factor. And 10^-15 is quite close to the expected 0.

Comment: I am running the code with an adaptive step size. So the result should be independent of tsteps variable. The solution of the ode is an exponent. So the answer should be exp(-500) = 7.12e-218, which is what I get for tsteps = 1000. The steps variable should not matter at all.

Comment: Actually the starting size has an impact. You should try to calculate the adapted size by hand. I'm pretty sure your absolute error in combination with the starting step size will yield a different adapted step size for your two variants.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I missed it. When I had tsteps = 1000 the inital step size was reset controlling the error. For tsteps = 100 the err_abs was dominating over err_rel, but that was not the case with tsteps = 1000 since the intial step size was reset at regular intervals. If I set err_abs = 0.0 then the result becomes independent of tsteps variable as expected.